# Global node-config variable undefined when testing with Jest

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, jestjs, node-config

I am implementing Option 2 from the [node-config docs](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Webpack-Usage).

This runs fine, and my global config variable is defined when running outside of a test environment.

However, when I run this with `vue-cli` and Jest unit testing (e.g. `vue-cli-service test:unit`), I get this error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: APP_CONFIG is not defined
```

```
// vue.config.js
...
 configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new ConfigWebpackPlugin('APP_CONFIG')
    ]
  },
...
```

What is a good way around this? Is it because Jest starts executing the JS files before the `node-config` can finish switching out all global variables with their values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jest does not run Webpack, so you would have to manually setup the config for your tests. As a workaround, you could declare the config as a Jest [global](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object).

To declare the global, add the `globals` property to the exported object in `jest.config.js`. The sub-property key would be the `config-webpack`'s namespace (`APP_CONFIG` in your case), and the value would be the required config JSON files from `config/`:

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    APP_CONFIG: require('./config/default.json')
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried setting `globals` in the Jest config but problem was the config was supposed to be dynamic (taking from test.json first, and then the rest from default.json). However, I suppose I can provide a complete copy of the test config. However, I think I may end up using option 1 here: https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Webpack-Usage

Comment: I see. Technically, you could still recreate that dynamic loading in `jest.config.js` with minimal effort.